# Mount(8) with mount(2)

Tags: filesystems, mount

I have a software that will unmount a partition programatically (if it's not busy) and mount it again after all of the work is done.

If I run this in the terminal:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/fat32 -o sync,dirsync,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro -t vfat
```

I get this in `/proc/self/mountinfo`:

```
100 24 8:17 / /mnt/fat32 rw,relatime shared:61 - vfat /dev/sdb1 rw,sync,dirsync,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,showexec,utf8,flush,errors=remount-ro
```

So I made a mountinfo parser andto get the data to restore the mount, but I'm having with converting mount options (`rw,relatime`) and super options (the last part in `/mountinfo`: `rw,sync,dirsync,`...) with `mountoptions` and `data`:

```
int mount(const char *source, const char *target,
          const char *filesystemtype, unsigned long mountflags,
          const void *data);
```

My approach was to convert the mount options into the appropriate `mountflags` and to give special options straight to `data`, but then I get this error:

```
[62857.390803] FAT-fs (sdb1): Unrecognized mount option "rw" or missing value
```

So I made a function to copy the attributes in the super options thet just matches the filesystem specific data, and now it works. But I still have a problem: how can I set, for instance, `sync` and `dirsync` if they are not in the mount options flags and if they aren't for vfat specific attributes?

If it can be made through the command line mount it can also be made in the command line version, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the parameters given to [`mount(8)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) are translated to flags specified in the `mountflags` parameter to [`mount(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html):

- `sync` is `MS_SYNCHRONOUS`;
- `dirsync` is `MS_DIRSYNC`;
- `relatime` is `MS_RELATIME`;
- `rw` is the default, so it can't be specified; `ro` would be `MS_RDONLY`.

Comment: so in my case mountflags it will be generated with /mountinfo mountoptions (rw,relatime) and non-filesystem specific options from the super options (e.g. rw, sync, dirsync)?

Comment: I think the general idea is to look for any options that match flags, process those, and then handle any remaining options. In your case, that would indeed cover `rw`, `relatime`, `sync` and `dirsync`.

Answer (score 1):

> *So I made a `mountinfo` parser* […]

You're better off using `setmntent()` and `getmntent()` that are provided in the GNU C runtime library.

> *My approach was to convert the mount options into the appropriate `mountflags` and to give special options straight to `data`* […]

What you need to do is take the `mnt_opts` given to you by `getmntent()` and process them into `flags` and `data`.  The `mount` command from the `util-linux` package relies upon a library for this, named *libmount*.  Some of it is table-driven, from lengthy Linux-specific tables.

### Further reading

- "[The `mtab` file](https://gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/mtab.html)". *The GNU C Library Reference Manual*.  2.23.  Free Software Foundation.  2016.
- Karel Zak (2012). "[Mount options](https://kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.21/libmount-docs/pt05.html)". *libmount Reference Manual*.  2.21.  Linux Kernel Archives.

Comment: getmntent() doesn't work (with me) with /mountinfo but only with the /proc/mounts structure, guess they just do a sscanf like I did for the parameters and /mountinfo have extra parameters. until now I didn't need any of the extra information in /mountinfo so I might change it to that

Comment: also, I remember reading somewhere (can't find the source now) that it was always better to read from /mountinfo, for some reason (portability?)